# Does potential energy get transferred from my body to a wall when I push a wall and fail to move it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

When I push a rock (and fail to move it), I do not do any work and therefore there should be no energy transfer.

But my teacher says that, when one pushes a rock, energy is transferred to the rock and is stored in the wall as potential energy.

I tried searching for answers on the internet, but even here, some say that no energy is transferred while others say that potential energy is transferred.

Can someone tell my what is really happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one thing pushes on another thing, the only way energy is *transferred* is if the pushing makes things move.  Without getting into calculus, it is sufficient to say that the amount of energy transferred depends on how hard the push, and on how far the things move.

When you push on something with your muscles, then your muscles are going to use energy, but if the thing does not move, then no energy was *transferred* to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the wall is not perfectly rigid, you will deform the wall slightly. There will be potential energy stored in the wall just the same as if you compressed a spring. When you release the pressure on the wall it will (assuming the deformation is elastic) return to its original shape, releasing the potential energy and doing work on your hand.

Comment: ok, but that potential energy would be negligible right

Comment: Yes, in most practical cases it would be negligible.

Comment: @aditya bharadwaj But you could get tired nonetheless. So work would get done within your muscles. On the other hand if one stone is placed on another, there could be deformation and storing of energy in the lower stone but no other work done in the upper one.