Why are there so many different definitions of Work in classical physics by different books and physicists , and which is correct?
Alot of different books , authors and physicists define work differently in classical physics and mechanics.
For example , Halliday & Resnick FUNDAMENTALS OF PHYSICS defines Work as

Work is energy transferred to or from an object by means of a force acting on
the object. Energy transferred to the object is positive work, and energy transferred
from the object is negative work.

Wikipedia also gives a similar definition,

In science, work is the energy transferred to or from an object via the application of force along a displacement

Link :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)
While for example Feynman lectures , Hewitt and Walter lewins open lectures define work as its own formula Work is integral of Force with respect to displacement
While John r. Taylor's classical mechanics defines it as change in Kinetic energy
Which is more accurate and why it can't be directly said as transfer of energy ?

They are manifestly the same thing!

Maby because there are so man different physicist writing books ;)

Taylor, in Classical Mechanics,  does not define work as change in Kinetic energy.He shows that is related to KE but he defines is as dot product of force and dispalcement (in differential form), as most everybody.

Interestingly, none of these definitions would consider the "work" done by an electrical circuit lighting a light or running a heater to be actually be work. I would define work as "energy usefully converted". I would include the caveat "usefully" because, for example, internal combustion engines produce more heat than motion - but motion is the goal.

I can appreciate your apparent frustration with the inconsistencies.
The Resnick statement "Work is energy transferred to or from an object by means of a force acting on the object" doesn’t include displacement. So as a definition of work it seems incomplete, unless you’ve left stuff out.
The Wikipedia article, which is similar to Feynman, is better, but it still lacks an important qualification, which is the displacement has to occur at the point where the force is applied. Static friction the ground applied to the drive wheel of a car causes it to accelerate without skidding, but the ground does no work (it doesn't transfer energy to the car). That's because there is no displacement of the point of application of the static friction force on the tire.
Taylor is incomplete (at least based on what you quoted). It sounds like the work energy theorem which is the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. I do work pushing a box at constant speed along a floor with kinetic friction even though there is no change in kinetic energy while I'm pushing it. That's because my work is not the net work done on the box. The net work is zero because my positive work equals the negative work done by kinetic friction for a net work of zero.
My view is the definition must include displacement of the point of application of the force.
Hope this helps.

To be fair, you are not giving energy to the wall, you are expending it by yourself.

@Javier I did say that. But the energy you expend is not physics (force x displacement) work. It is physiological work, as I explained in my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/594783/where-does-the-energy-get-transferred-when-we-push-the-wall

The Resnick statement seems to apply fine to the case of the motionless wall: No energy is transferred to it by means of a force, so no work is done on it.

@Chemomechanics you’re right. I didn’t read the whole thing. I will update. But it still isn’t a definition of work as it doesn’t include displacement

Well, the very next sentence (of the chapter summary) reads "The work done on a particle by a constant force during displacement is $W=Fd\cos\theta=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{d}$ (work, constant force)". The premise of the original question is arguably incorrect, as @nasu has also pointed out. This is a case of incomplete reading and selective quoting. A single sentence in a textbook doesn't preclude fuller interpretation of a concept.

@Chemomechanics that’s always the problem answering posts that quote stuff out of context.  With Taylor I said “at less what you quoted” The same should apply to Resnick and the others.

@Chemomechanics p.s. I’ve edited to include the same caveat for Resnick

@Chemomechanics Even the ${\bf F} \cdot {\bf d}$ definition is incorrect. If I push an object to slide over a frictional surface, I don't do work on it. I guess I don't because I believe the work concept is confusing. Energy - heat, kinetic and potential - covers it all.

@my2cts you do positive work on it. But kinetic friction also does negative work on it. The net work is the sum of your work and friction work. That equals the change in kinetic energy of the object

@BobD If friction does do (negative) work then I don't see any difference between work and energy. The term 'work' only creates confusion.

@my2cts I'm sorry but I don't follow you. When you do positive work on the box you transfer energy to the box giving it KE equal to your work. But friction, by doing negative work , simultaneously takes away  some or all of the mechanical kinetic it acquired from you, depending on how much work you and it does, increasing the molecular KE of the materials increasing their temperature and eventually dissipated as heat.

@BobD So friction can also do work. What then is the difference between work done and energy transferred?

@my2cts Yes friction can do work. Work done by friction can transfer energy to something. That’s positive work and typically  involves static friction. Work done by friction can also transfer energy away from something. That’s negative work and typically involves kinetic friction.

And work IS the transfer of energy due to force times displacement

@BobD Energy transfer by absorption of radiation, is that work? Or by contact with a body of different temperature (this could be viewed as friction)? What types of energy transfer are work and which types are not? It seems that the discussion is one about definition, not about physical concept.

Energy transfer due to temperature difference is heat. Energy transfer due to force times displacement is work.  Electromagnetic radiation, depending on frequency and the type of material, may be either. For example,  the radiation from microwave ovens raises the temperature of something  due to electromagnetic work (field giving dipoles rotational KE, not temperature difference) while raising the temperature  by the heating elements in an oven is heat (temperature difference) For other frequencies, see:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod3.html Friction is work.

All the mentioned definitions are equivalent:

Your first two are stated in text,
your third one is stated mathematically,
and your fourth one is of experimental origin.

(I would, though, say that the first one is rather short and less precise since it leaves out any mention of displacement and thus can't be used alone.)
The precise mathematical definition of work is:
$$W=\int \mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf r,$$
and in words this indeed can be phrased as something like "transferred energy $W$ when a force $\mathbf F$ influences a displacement" ($\mathbf r$ is the displacement vector). Using words, such definitions become less precise, or at least not unique as there could be many equivalent formulations. This is the nature of language. The mathematical definition is a safer choice - that is our only precise "language".
Now, your fourth one is actually going back to the roots and is the origin for the other equivalent definitions. This one gives a practical means of defining work as follows: In a scenario where only the energy of motion (kinetic energy) changes, then the energy conservation law reduces to:
$$K_1+W=K_2.$$
The $W$ term represents energy that is added to the system and which causes the change in kinetic energy. This $W$ has then been given a name: Work. It turns out that this $W$ is added to the system due to forces that cause a displacement of the system - you can show that this is perfectly equivalent to the mathematical definition mentioned above.
